# How to use Math.min() and Math.max() in a function with n arguments?

Tags: function, arguments, mean

I'm a beginner, and I'm trying to write a function to calculate the mean of the smallest and highest numbers in any given sequence of numbers. However, I haven't been able to insert the right command inside the parameters of the method. Can you guys help me?

Here's my code:

```
function midrange () {
let min = Math.min(arguments);
let max = Math.max(arguments);
let mean = (min + max) / 2;
  console.log("min:", min);
  console.log("max:", max);
return mean;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to pass arguments Value in your Method. If it's not declared Globally

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```js
function midrange (...arguments) {
let min = Math.min(...arguments);
let max = Math.max(...arguments);
let mean = (min + max) / 2;
  console.log("min:", min);
  console.log("max:", max);
  console.log(mean)
return mean;
}

midrange(1, 2, 4,7, 1, 2 ,3 ,5)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters?retiredLocale=uk

Answer (score 0):

You could use **[Spread syntax (`...`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)**:

```js
function midrange(...arguments) {
  const min = Math.min(...arguments);
  console.log(`min: ${min}`);
  const max = Math.max(...arguments);
  console.log(`max: ${max}`);
  return (min + max) / 2;
}

console.log(`midrange: ${midrange(1, 2, 3)}`);
```